# remove words that consists of numbers and string punctuations from text

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Is there a better/efficient way to remove words that consist of either numbers, or string punctuations or a combination these two from some text?

example 1:

```
 input_text: 'This is a test number +223/34 and this a real number 2333.'
    expected_output =  'This is a test number and this a real number .'
```

example 2:

```
input_text: 'This is a test-number +223/34 and this a real number 2333. The email is test@gmail.com and the website is www.test.com which sells 3-D products'
    expected_output =  'This is a test-number and this a real number . The email is test@gmail.com and the website is www.test.com which sells 3-D products.
```

Currently, I have something like this.

```
def is_valid_word(word):
    return not word.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)).isdigit()

clean_text    = " ".join([word for word in input_text.split() if is_valid_word(word)])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check if a token is alphanumeric:

```py
clean_text  = " ".join([word for word in input_text.split() if word.isalnum()])
```

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/mANKd4):

```py
input_text = 'This is a test number +223/34 and this a real number 2333.'
print( " ".join([word for word in input_text.split() if word.isalnum()]) )
# => This is a test number and this a real number
```

If you have specific patterns in mind, you can write specific regex patterns to find the matching strings and delete them with `re.sub`. For example, if you want to remove standalone numbers that can contain match operators between them, or dots/commas, you can use the following:

```py
import re
input_text = 'This is a test number +223/34 and this a real number 2333. The email is test@gmail.com and the website is www.test.com.'
print( re.sub(r'[-+]?\b\d+(?:[.,+/*-]\d+)*\b', '', input_text) )
```

that yields the expected:

```
This is a test number  and this a real number . The email is test@gmail.com and the website is www.test.com.
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/LjuPBu). The regex means

- `[-+]?` - an optional `+` or `-`
- `\b` - a word boundary (the digit cannot be glued to a word)
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(?:[.,+/*-]\d+)*` - zero or more repetitions of `.` / `,` / `+`, `/`, `*`, `-` and then one or more digits
- `\b` - a word boundary (the digit cannot be glued to a word).

Comment: Good one. However, some words in the text contain hypens which will also be removed by isalnum. The text can contain words that might not be alphanumeric but still valid for my use-case.

Comment: @utengr Then "subtract" that hyphen, `" ".join([word for word in input_text.split() if word.replace('-','').isalnum()])`. If you need a more "elegant" solution, you need to define what kind of chars a "word" can consist of. Mind that in the regex world, a regex is a combination of letters, digits, diacritics and connector punctuation. You are using a whitespace tokenization approach when using `str.split`.

Comment: I could do that. However, I still risk removing words that might not be alphanum. Another example is an email address something@gmail.com, or some website name.  That's why the focus is on what I know I want to remove which are words that only consist of numbers, string punctuations or a combination of the two.

Comment: Maybe I will change the test case to better capture the use-case.

Comment: @utengr The problem here is defining the "word" boundaries. You want to keep dots at the end of the sentence, but the dot is a part of `string.punctuation`, and thus `2222.` fits the deletion rule. A totally different solution may be required here, something like https://ideone.com/LjuPBu.

Comment: Regex solutions are fine too. Maybe you can add this regex link to your answer and i can accept it after testing it.

Comment: How to handle cases like `"The temperature was -2°C"` or `"That is 100% correct"`?

Comment: @ekhumoro See [this demo](https://ideone.com/Ap6CwW), `re.sub(r'[-+]?\b\d+(?:[.,+/*-]\d+)*(?:°C)?\b[%‰]?', '', input_text)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sure, but those are just two examples - it's not difficult to come up others (e.g. urls with paths that contain something like `"/1/2/"`). As you pointed out earlier, the real problem is how to determine what a "word" is. Or rather what a *lexical unit* is (according to the OPs requirements).

Comment: @ekhumoro Sorry, let OP decide.

Comment: I don't know how to put the definition of the word here when it comes the last word of the sentence or a word in the middle followed by a comma. But  it would be fine if '22/3, test' is converted to ' , test' or 'test'.  Or For 'test 22-33.', both 'test' and 'test .' are acceptable.

Comment: @utengr Maybe you want to keep any word with at least one letter? `" ".join([word for word in input_text.split() if any(x.isalpha() for x in word)])`. See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/zzmHyD).

Answer (score 1):

Your method seems ok, but if you want to use a regex (like the tag suggests) you can use this to capture all the characters that are not lower/uppercase letters or spaces:

```
[^a-zA-Z ]*
```

Then you can replace with an empty string.

```
import re

input_text = "This is a test number +223/34 and this a real number 2333."
clean_text=re.sub("[^a-zA-Z ]*", "", input_text)
```